# Flutter Web Azure AD (Entra) authentication with aad_OAuth not working

Tags: flutter, azure, dart, azure-active-directory, entra

I currently trying to realize an Azure Active Directory authentication in Flutter Web using the aad_OAuth (v1.0.0, last version) plackage from pub.dev.

I just grab the example from the package and configure it with my informations.

Here is the main.dart file:

```
import 'package:aad_oauth/aad_oauth.dart';
import 'package:aad_oauth/model/config.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'AAD OAuth Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'AAD OAuth Home'),
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static final Config config = Config(
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:64444/",
    tenant: '******',
    clientId: '******',
    scope: 'openid profile offline_access',
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    loader: SizedBox(),
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('AAD OAuth Demo'),
    ),
    clientSecret: '******',
  );

  final AadOAuth oauth = AadOAuth(config);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              'AzureAD OAuth',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.launch),
            title: Text('Login${kIsWeb ? ' (web popup)' : ''}'),
            onTap: () {
              login(false);
            },
          ),
          if (kIsWeb)
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.launch),
              title: Text('Login (web redirect)'),
              onTap: () {
                login(true);
              },
            ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.data_array),
            title: Text('HasCachedAccountInformation'),
            onTap: () => hasCachedAccountInformation(),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.logout),
            title: Text('Logout'),
            onTap: () {
              logout();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void showError(dynamic ex) {
    print(ex.toString());
    showMessage(ex.toString());
  }

  void showMessage(String text) {
    var alert = AlertDialog(content: Text(text), actions: <Widget>[
      TextButton(
          child: const Text('Ok'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          })
    ]);
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => alert);
  }

  void login(bool redirect) async {
    config.webUseRedirect = redirect;
    final result = await oauth.login();
    result.fold(
      (l) => showError(l.toString()),
      (r) => showMessage('Logged in successfully, your access token: $r'),
    );
    var accessToken = await oauth.getAccessToken();
    if (accessToken != null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(accessToken)));
    }
  }

  void hasCachedAccountInformation() async {
    var hasCachedAccountInformation = await oauth.hasCachedAccountInformation;
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content:
            Text('HasCachedAccountInformation: $hasCachedAccountInformation'),
      ),
    );
  }

  void logout() async {
    await oauth.logout();
    showMessage('Logged out');
  }
}
```

When executing this dart code with `flutter run -d chrome --web-port=64444` and using the popup method for authenticating, popup start well, i can authenticate with Microsot AZURE well.

But when the popup close, i return on Flutter application and the MSAL Browser library call the url `https://login.microsoftonline.com/****/oauth2/v2.0/token` to get access token. And the POST request fail with:

```
AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
```

It try with setting a secret in AZURE AD and without. In both case i get this message.

AZURE AD is configure with a web redirect URY equal to `http://localhost:64444/`

I have read many post asking to set **Allow public customer flows** to yes, that'"s what i do.

At this time i don't know if it's a problem with my AZURE configuration or if it's a problem with my code or aad_OAuth code.

Last, i also try with an SPA redirection URI, but in this case i got this error:

```
AADSTS9002327: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests.
```

**EDIT**

The POST request to token endpoint don't contains the client_secret parameter.

So what i do is capturing the POST request as curl format from chrome devtools. Then, if i execute the curl after adding manually the client_secret, the token endpoint respond by sending the access token.

So it seems that the MSAL lib used by aad_oauth package not using the clientSecret provide by the package.

Comment: I would suggest you to try out https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android and use Flutter method channel to call native code.

Comment: @ZohaibTariq I am not under Android platform, but Web Platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED**

Problem is with headers sent by chrome navigator to AZURE AD.

For debugging purpose, chrome browser was launched by the `flutter run -d chrome` command with the `--disable-web-security` flag.

With this flag, AZURE AD issue the AADSTS9002327: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests. error message.

Launching chrome without this flag make the request accepted by AZURE AD.